# I encountered issues with the embedded API while retrieve analytics data, and it appears that the APIs are not compatible with GA4

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I've been facing challenges with the embedded API for Google Analytics while trying to fetch data for GA4.
Despite attempting to adapt UA API calls using the GA4 query explorer, the process seems ineffective. Although passing UA data yields results, transitioning to GA4 demands additional parameters, and I'm still struggling to obtain the desired analytics data.

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9cMK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1whOe.png)

Is there a way to convert embedded API calls to GA4 API calls? Currently, the embedded API is not returning data after July 2023. I am seeking an API that can provide similar data to what I am fetching from the UA embedded API

My primary objective is to utilise this data to showcase analytics details on my admin page.

Answer (score 0):

The embeded api only works with Universal analytics.

I asked the team a while ago if they would be updating it to GA4 they said there was no plans to do so.